# Sticky with overflow-auto remove gap

Tags: css, overflow, sticky

I have this content with `overflow-auto` and inside a `sticky` on top and bottom. I want the sticky elements to be part of the content itself and don't have an extra space.

Because this is a simple example you can use a workaround of define the `background-color` with `red`, but I don't want that, it cannot be applied to my complex case.

**Problem:**

[image]

**Ideal**

[image]

```css
.container {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.content {
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
  background: red;
}

.stickie-top {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.stickie-bottom {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="stickie-top">Sticky top</div>
  <div class="content">Lorem ipsum ...</div>
  <div class="stickie-bottom">Sticky bottom</div>
</div>
```

You can see the example in this: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n0dix/cxpeg935/46/)

Comment: are you just wanting the background colour of top and bottom to be red when not stuck?  If so why not apply the background to the container rather than the content?

Comment: @Pete, I have explained in OP that this example is a simpler case I have. In my real case, apply a `background-color` won't solve the issue. I will make the jsfiddle more accurate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make their height equal to 0. For the bottom sticky you will need extra CSS to rectify the alignment

```css
.container {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.content {
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
  background: red;
}

.stickie-top {
  position: sticky;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height:0;
}

.stickie-bottom {
  position: sticky;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  height:0;
  display:flex;
  align-items:flex-end;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="stickie-top">Sticky top</div>
  <div class="content">Lorem ipsum ...</div>
  <div class="stickie-bottom">Sticky bottom</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code. It will help to solve your problem.

```css
body{
  margin: 0;
}
.container {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  overflow: auto;
  background: red;
}

.content {
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
}

.stickie-top {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.stickie-bottom {
  position: sticky;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="stickie-top">Sticky top</div>
  <div class="content">Lorem ipsum ...</div>
  <div class="stickie-bottom">Sticky bottom</div>
</div>
```